# wallet_addEthereumChain returns runtime error even though the network changed

Tags: ethereum, metamask, ethers.js

I am calling this in my NextJS React app:

`provider.send('wallet_addEthereumChain', [networkMaps[networkName]])`

Which results in this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: underlying network changed (event="changed", network={"name":"matic","chainId":137,"ensAddress":null}, detectedNetwork={"name":"maticmum","chainId":80001,"ensAddress":null,"_defaultProvider":null}, code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

[image]

Though when I check metamask, the network was changed.
Any ideas why this error pops up?

Also when I wrap that call in a try/catch, the catch does not catch the above Error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Solved this using this solution of adding any to the provider:
https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react/issues/127